# Remove black background of alpha brush

Tags: texture-painting

[image]

Is there a way to remove the black background of an alpha brush in Blender without having to manually remove each one? I would also like to know if there is a way to change the properties of texture painted patterns? I would like this yellow to look like gold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your image as a Brush Mask instead of as a Brush - in the texture settings, set it to Calculate Alpha, and you will be able to set your Brush color to anything you want.
[image]